# Why do I keep getting a error message for import when I try to run my code?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I am new to tkinter and jupyter notebook but I am currently working on a GUI project. I am trying to get my project to show me the entire run of the console in a text area(result_text). Here is my code

```
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import select, subprocess, tempfile
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from subprocess import DEVNULL, PIPE


#web window
window = Tk()

window.title("NT3 Application")

window.geometry('880x550')

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + '\\..')
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
    
    
space_label0 = Label(window, text= "", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label0.grid(column=0, row=0)

space_label1 = Label(window, text= "", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label1.grid(column=0, row=1)

space_label2= Label(window, text= "", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label2.grid(column=0, row=3)

space_label3= Label(window, text= "", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label3.grid(column=0, row=4)

space_label4= Label(window, text= "", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label4.grid(column=0, row=8)

#Results_textbox
results_label= Label(window, text= "Result", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
results_label.grid(column=3, row=6)

result_text= Text(window, height=20, width=40 )
result_text.grid(column=3, row=7)

#Name_textbox
name_label = Label(window, text= "        Name ", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
name_label.grid(column=2, row=3)

name_textbox = Text(window, height=1, width=20 )
name_textbox.grid(column=3, row=3)


#Status_dropbox
status_label = Label(window, text= "Status ", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
status_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

combo = Combobox(window, text = "Model")
combo['values']= ("Select","Epochs","Time")

combo.current(0) 
combo.grid(column=1, row=3)

#Run_function
def run_model_text():
    with subprocess.Popen([ "nt3_baseline_keras2.py" ], stdout=PIPE) as P:
        while True:
            line = P.stdout.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        print("line: " + str(line))
#Run_button
run_btn = Button(window, text="Run",command=run_model_text)
run_btn.grid(column=4, row=3)

#Savebutton
def save_file():
    myFile = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    if myFile is None:
       return
    data = result_text.get(1.0,'end')
    myFile.write(data)
    myFile.close 
# Create a button to save the text
save = Button(window, text="Save", command=save_file)
save.grid(column=3, row=8)    
    
#Plot
plot_label= Label(window, text= "Plot", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
plot_label.grid(column=1, row=6)

#temperaryplotbox
tempplot_textbox = Text(window, height=20, width=40 )
tempplot_textbox.grid(column=1, row=7)


window.main()
```

The problem with the code is that I keep getting the error "SyntaxError: import * only allowed at module level" but I am not sure why my code is producing this error. Does anyone have any tips or pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: I get at least a couple other errors when I run your code. Please make sure that the code actually reproduces the problem, and please reduce the code down to a minimum. If the problem is with the import statements, we probably don't need any of the code that creates widgets.

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to try and not use `*` imports at all. Better to just import normally and access the functions with the module name or only import what you need with `from`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import select, subprocess, tempfile
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from subprocess import DEVNULL, PIPE

#Add os and sys import
import os, sys
# web window
window = Tk()

window.title("NT3 Application")

window.geometry('880x550')

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd() + '\\..')
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

space_label0 = Label(window, text="", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label0.grid(column=0, row=0)

space_label1 = Label(window, text="", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label1.grid(column=0, row=1)

space_label2 = Label(window, text="", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label2.grid(column=0, row=3)

space_label3 = Label(window, text="", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label3.grid(column=0, row=4)

space_label4 = Label(window, text="", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
space_label4.grid(column=0, row=8)

# Results_textbox
results_label = Label(window, text="Result", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
results_label.grid(column=3, row=6)

result_text = Text(window, height=20, width=40)
result_text.grid(column=3, row=7)

# Name_textbox
name_label = Label(window, text="        Name ", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
name_label.grid(column=2, row=3)

name_textbox = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
name_textbox.grid(column=3, row=3)

# Status_dropbox
status_label = Label(window, text="Status ", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
status_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

combo = Combobox(window, text="Model")
combo['values'] = ("Select", "Epochs", "Time")

combo.current(0)
combo.grid(column=1, row=3)


# Run_function
def run_model_text():
    with subprocess.Popen(["nt3_baseline_keras2.py"], stdout=PIPE) as P:
        while True:
            line = P.stdout.readline()
            if len(line) == 0:
                break
        print("line: " + str(line))


# Run_button
run_btn = Button(window, text="Run", command=run_model_text)
run_btn.grid(column=4, row=3)


# Savebutton
def save_file():
    myFile = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    if myFile is None:
        return
    data = result_text.get(1.0, 'end')
    myFile.write(data)
    myFile.close


# Create a button to save the text
save = Button(window, text="Save", command=save_file)
save.grid(column=3, row=8)

# Plot
plot_label = Label(window, text="Plot", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
plot_label.grid(column=1, row=6)

# temperaryplotbox
tempplot_textbox = Text(window, height=20, width=40)
tempplot_textbox.grid(column=1, row=7)

# not window.main() instead window.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```

I couldn't recreate the error but you forgot to import os and sys and used at the end the wrong Methodname `window.mainloop()` not `window.main()` This is working for me except for the Run Button